# Taxonomy template for all taxonomies attached to certain post type

Tags: taxonomy, templates, get-template-part

For instance, I have a product post type and I would like all the taxonomies associated w/ this type, such as size, color, material etc to display using the same template without having to 1. create a catch all taxonomy.php that might interfere w/ taxonomies on other post types and 2. without having to manually create taxonomy-size.php, taxonomy-color.php, etc since new taxonomies can be created at any time.

can i do this by hijacking template redirect?

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer so this doesn't haunt site as unanswered.

Comment: done. trying to go back and solve my unanswereds....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is yes, yes i can.  do love it when i find the answer w/in minutes of posting here.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template');

function my_template() {
    if ( is_tax() && in_array(get_query_var('taxonomy'), get_object_taxonomies('product') ) ){
        include (get_stylesheet_directory(). '/product_taxonomy.php');
        exit;   
    }
}
```